# Pass property as parameter to create a filtering method with LINQ/C#?

Tags: c#, linq, filter, properties

Suppose I have these classes:

```
private class Model
{
    public DateTime FirstDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime SecondDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime FinalDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
private class Mommasan : Bandana
{
    public DateTime RestDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime TurboDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

All dates need to be filtered up to 3 days. So how can I create a generic filtering method for the `DateTime` properties? Using `IQueryable`? I was hoping it would end up something like this:

(Obviously will not compile, but I'm guessing the idea)

```
void DoSpecificFilter<T>(ref IQueryable<T> query, DateTimeProperty property)
{
    DateTime today = today;
    query = query.Where(a => property <= today && today <= property.AddDays(3);
}
```

So if I need to filter `Models` who are on their final date, something like:

```
DoSpecificFilter<Model>(ref alreadyFilteredQuery, a => a.FinalDate);
```

and `Mommasans` who are on rest:

```
DoSpecificFilter<Mommasan>(ref alreadyFilteredQuery, a => a.RestDate);
```

Is this kind of thing possible at all or am I having the entirely wrong idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could work with `DateTime`-Selectors. For multiple `DateTime` fields you would have to chain them together. It would probably be easier to write an extention method for this:

```
public static class ExtentionMethods
{
    public static IQueryable<T> DoSpecificFilter<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> query, 
        Expression<Func<T, DateTime>> dateSelector, 
        DateTime filterValue, 
        bool blnTopLimit)
    {
        return query.Where(a => (blnTopLimit && dateSelector.Compile()(a) < filterValue)
            || (!blnTopLimit && dateSelector.Compile()(a) > filterValue));
    }
 }
```

Then you could use it like this:

```
 var query = queryableCollection
     .DoSpecificFilter((a) => a.RestDate, DateTime.Today, false)
     .DoSpecificFilter((a) => a.TurboDate, DateTime.Today, true);
```

Comment: Intuition tells me this won't work, because LINQ doesn't accept `Func`s, but `Expressions`. Changing the parameter type to `Expression<Func<T, DateTime>>` should work. You can still use it the same way with lambdas.

Comment: @V0ldek Thanks for the hint. I changed it.

Comment: Hey thanks, but what's the final `bool` parameter for?

Comment: @AwonDanag For specifying if you want a `DateTime` property to be before or after the given timestamp.

Comment: Can the `where T : ` bit be generic or a parameter as well?

Comment: @AwonDanag Actually, I don't think it is necessary anymore, but have not tested it.

Comment: @DeveloperExceptionError I think you're missing a `<T>` after the method name, and why does `dateSelector(a)` don't work?

Comment: @AwonDanag I added the missing `<T>`. The `dateSelector(a)` does not work because we needed to switch to an `Expression<T>`. That means that we have to use `dateSelector.Compile()(a)`. Added it to the answer.

Comment: @AwonDanag It should.

Comment: @DeveloperExceptionError Thanks for the quick response, but it says 'The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.'

Comment: @AwonDanag Then it probably is not possible at the moment to use a generic method with your Linq to Entities here.

Answer (score 0):

Why not write an extension method on DateTime, and not look at the class at all? Something like ...

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> DoSpecificFilter<T>(this DateTime value, IQueryable<T> query)
    {
        DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
        IQueryable<T> ret = query.Where(a => value <= today && today <= value.AddDays(3));
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see why it wouldn't .. give it a bash?

Comment: I think it wouldn't, because I don't see any pointers to the property being filtered...